# Javascript challenge - which basket contains the last apple?

Tags: javascript

I'm presented with the following challenge question:

> There are a circle of 100 baskets in a room; the baskets are numbered
>   in sequence from 1 to 100 and each basket contains one apple. 
>   Eventually, the apple in basket 1 will be removed but the apple in
>   basket 2 will be skipped.  Then the apple in basket 3 will be removed.
>   This will continue (moving around the circle, removing an apple from a
>   basket, skipping the next) until only one apple in a basket remains.
>   Write some code to determine in which basket the remaining apple is
>   in.

I concluded that basket 100 will contain the last apple and here's my code:

```
     var allApples = [];
        var apples = [];
        var j = 0;
        var max = 100; 
        var o ='';
            while (j < max) {
                o += ++j;
                allApples.push(j);
            }

            var apples = allApples.filter(function(val) {
                return 0 == val % 2;
            });
            while (apples.length > 1) {
                for (i = 0; i < apples.length; i += 2) {
                    apples.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }

            console.log(apples);
```

My question is: did I do this correctly?  What concerns me is the description of "a circle" of baskets.  I'm not sure this is relevant at all to how I code my solution.  And would the basket in which the remaining apple reside be one that would otherwise be skipped?

I hope someone can let me know if I answered this correctly, answered it partially correct or my answer is entirely wrong.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the problem quite a bit. Let's start with 5 apples in a circle. We remove the 1st, the 3rd, and the 5th in the first phase, leaving the 2nd and the 4th. Now, after we remove the 5th, the next basket is the 2nd. So, we skip the second, remove the 4th, and leave just the 2nd, and that's our last basket. Your solution just removes all odd apples, which is just the first step. We still need to skip every other basket as we continue around the circle.

Comment: wow ... so basically, my mistake was in thinking that I only need to do the process once i.e. remove the odd, skip the remaining even numbered ones until I get to the last basket.  In other words, it's not just about odd vs even, it's about applying the correct iterative pattern.  Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Interestingly, this pattern is actually reducible to a single non-iterative statement, but the correct iterative pattern is more interesting than regurgitating a formula.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "but the correct iterative pattern is more interesting than regurgitating a formula."  If you could provide a simple example of what you mean here, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, ... I got WAY too into this question :)

I broke out the input/output of my last answer and that revealed a pretty simple pattern.

Basically, if the total number of items is a power of 2, then it will be the last item. An additional item after that will make the second item the last item. Each additional item after that will increase the last item by 2, until you reach another item count that is again divisible by a power of 2. Rinse and repeat.

Still not a one-liner, but will be much faster than my previous answer. This will not work for 1 item.

```
var items = 100;

function greatestPowDivisor(n, p) {
    var i = 1;
    while(n - Math.pow(p, i) > 0) {
        i++;
    }
    return Math.pow(p, (i - 1));
}

var d = greatestPowDivisor(items, 2)
var last_item = (items - d) * 2;
```

Comment: Fantastic work!  Do you think I'm even a little close with this code:

var lastApple = function(){
    while(allApples.length > 1){
    for(i=0; i<allApples.length; i+=2){
     if(allApples.length > 1){
      allApples.splice(i, 1);
     } else {
      console.log(allApples.length);
      allApples.length = 0;
     }   
     }
     
    }
   };

Comment: You're close but doing too much. Here is a simplified version of your code that accomplishes the same (wrong) result: http://jsfiddle.net/GALFg/ The problem is that the loop always removes the first (0) item. You need a way to determine whether or not to skip or remove the first item.

Comment: Hmmm, but I thought it should remove the first item based upon this sentence of the challenge which states: "Eventually, the apple in basket 1 will be removed but the apple in basket 2 will be skipped. Then the apple in basket 3 will be removed."  Doesn't basket 1 === element 0?  And if I remove that element, another remaining element will assume that position in the array, right?

Comment: here's a modified fiddle of the simplified code you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/GALFg/1/  This gives a result of 82 ... still wrong?

Comment: Yes, on the first pass you will remove the apple in basket 1. The question is: Do you remove or skip the first apple on the second, third, fourth, etc. passes?

Comment: Based on the info provided, it seemed clear that yes, the code should always remove the 0th element.

Comment: I disagree. "This will continue (moving around the circle, removing an apple from a basket, skipping the next) until only one apple in a basket remains." The baskets are in a circle. The transition from basket #100 to basket #1 has no meaning and should not interrupt the apple removal process.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Colin DeClue is right that there is a single statement that will solve this pattern. I would be really interested to know that answer.

Here is my brute force solution. Instead of moving items ("apples") from their original container ("basket") into a discard pile, I am simply changing the container values from true or false to indicate that an item is no longer present.

```
var items = 100;
var containers = [];

// Just building the array of containers
for(i=0; i<items; i++) {
    containers.push(true);
}

// count all containers with value of true
function countItemsLeft(containers) {
    total = 0;
    for(i=0; i<containers.length; i++) {
        if(containers[i]) {
            total++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

// what is the index of the first container
// with a value of true - hopefully there's only one
function getLastItem(containers) {
    for(i=0; i<containers.length; i++) {
        if(containers[i]) {
            return(i);
        }
    }
    // shouldn't get here if the while loop did it's job
    return false;
}

var skip = false;
// loop through the items,
// setting every other to false,
// until there is only 1 left
while(countItemsLeft(containers) > 1) {
    for(i=0; i<containers.length; i++) {
        if(containers[i]) {
            if(skip) {
                skip = false;
            } else {
                containers[i] = false;
                skip = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

// what's the last item? add one to account for 0 index
// to get a human readable answer
var last_item  = getLastItem(containers) + 1;
```

Needs error checking, etc... but it should get the job done assuming items is an integer.

Comment: so what result does it produce?  what is the last basket?  I got 93 from the last code I posted on an answer just below, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: I get 72. What is this for ?

Comment: I just reworked my code and got 82 ... what to think?  I will edit my question post my code again.  

This is for some course work I'm going through to improve my coding skills.